# Sending authorize request to twitter API for followers ids

Tags: twitter, smalltalk, pharo

I want to send authorize request to twitter API in order to get followers ids, i got access token and access token secret by creating a new application as shown [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom). I have no idea how to send authorize request in pharo smalltalk.

I want to get followers ids by performing [this in pharo smalltalk](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) .
I wanna know if there is any documentation or packages that can help me with this.

Here is the code i tried to work with.

```
|client|
client:= ZnClient new.
client https;
host: 'www.api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json';
queryAt: 'q' put: 'cursor=-1&screen_name=my name'.
client request headers at: 'Authorization' put:' OAuth  oauth_consumer_key="Hp6FpBU7Bbqv89RqrHJzHw", oauth_nonce="9677be3a12e128702b06348677319e75", oauth_signature="GUQR%2FI%2Bd0XhQLJP5B0IHtDfiiLE%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1387729271", oauth_token=" my acess token", oauth_version="1.0" '. 
client get.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Pharo community, Irfan.

You should take a look at [Zinc](http://zn.stfx.eu/zn/index.html) framework. [Here](http://zn.stfx.eu/zn/zinc-http-components-paper.html) is a very nice documentation, you should be able to solve your problem after reading it.

Also as far as I know there is work in progress on the OAuth protocol, you can take a look here: https://github.com/svenvc/docs/blob/master/zinc/zinc-sso-paper.md. You definitely want to take a look at it because there are also 2 demos where you can interact with twitter

Comment: Thanks for above documentation. I tried to sent the request with ZnClient  my code doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @Irfan can you be more specific? What request did you make, and what response did you get?

Comment: I am having hard time figuring this out, I created a twitter application and i got the OAuth access token,consumer key, consumer secret parameters. I don't understand whats the next step after this and How do i send request to twitter API 1.1 to get the followers ids. Is there any example or some help with code.

Comment: @Irfan have you looked at Zinc SSO? Here are some examples: https://github.com/svenvc/docs/blob/master/zinc/zinc-sso-paper.md#oauth-10a-support you can also take a look at implementation (when you load the code)